# Error when installing redmine on ubuntu 13.10

Tags: ruby, redmine, ubuntu-13.10

I'm new to Redmine and Ruby, i would just like to run Redmine(2.4.1). I just follow this [instructions](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_Install_Redmine_212_in_Ubuntu_1210_and_Apache_Passenger) , but i encountered this error when i enter this command `sudo apt-get install ruby rubygems libruby libapache2-mod-passenger ruby-dev`

```
/usr/local/bin/rake:23:in `load': no such file to load -- /usr/share/rubygems-integration/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/bin/rake (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/bin/rake:23
dpkg: error processing redmine (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
```

Thank for any comment and answer :-)

Comment: From the error, it looks like there is something going on with rake (either it isn't installed at all, or not working with the version of Ruby you're using). Try `gem install rake`, and then try again and see if that helps.

Comment: Thank @MattMcNaughton, after wait for a long time, I install Redmine on Ubuntu 12.10 and no error was found :-)